# Reliable dictionary vs Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, reliable-dictionary

I want to implement caching for Cosmos DB data. I read about Reliable Dictionary and Redis Cache.

I want to know:

(1) When to use Reliable Dictionary as a caching mechanism and what is the duration and capacity of cache?

(2) Redis cache is recommended but what is the capacity and duration of availability?

Answer (score 0):

A reliable dictionary is a collection in c#, not a Service. The capacity depends on the memory of the service you host your application (e. g. App Service, Service Fabric, etc...). Also **you** have to **manage** the duration of the cach entries.

Redis Cache is Caching **as a Service**. The Capacity depends on the SKU and is up to 530GB. You have different ways to control the duration of an entry. You can use a absolute (datetime) or sliding expiration (e. g. a entry get removed when not accessed within the last 30 minutes).